# How to update custom field in JIRA via REST API?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

This (resolution description) custom filed should be updated while the "resolution" changed to "fixed" so I used the "transition" REST API call to do it.i have passes the following jason string via REST API call.but no sign of working as expected. can't I change those two fields with "transition" REST API call?

```
{"update": {"resolution description": [{ "add": { "body": "" + errors + "" }}]},
"transition": { "id": "5" }}
```

"errors" is a variable with hard-coded value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer for this question.I also put this question in [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/28509781/answers/28509826/comments/28868783). To update a custom field using REST API you can basically write a JSON string like this. For more information follow [this link](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis) and this site clearly include everything need to know when going to access JIRA custom fields by REST API.

```
{
    "fields": {
        "customfield_id": {"This is a shorthand for a set operation on a text custom field"},
        "resolution": {"name": "Fixed"}
    },
    "transition": {
        "id": "5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not forget to consider the type of the Jira field, which must match what you send. Setting a numeric value with a string, even if it's a number, will fail.